# How to make a lift scan numbers

Tags: java, println

\ the lift at the moment has the functionality that people can get in the lift leave the lift and it scans the floor that they selected but then when the next person selects a floor they are unable to go from anywhere but 0 even though they can select any of the 7 floors they want to.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class LiftLogin {

    private static int CurrentFloor;
    static int RequestedFloor;
    private static Scanner next2;
    private static int i;

    public static <infinite> void main(final String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        {
            Scanner authentification = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Passname;
            System.out.println("Please enter your Encrypted Passname");
            Passname = authentification.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Doors Opening");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            int attempts = 0;

            if (Passname.equals("uzp mwzrrd")) {
                System.out.println("Access Granted For Joe Bloggs");
            } else if (Passname.equals("ncltr dxtes")) {
                System.out.println("Access Granted For Craig Smith");
            } else if (Passname.equals("nsctd zyptw")) {
                System.out.println("Access Granted For Chris ONeil");
            } else if (Passname.equals("pxxl dezyp")) {
                System.out.println("Access Granted For Emma Stone");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Passname");
            }
            {
                attempts++;
                if (attempts >= 3) {
                    System.out.println("\nYou've had 3 Attempts, you have been denied Access");
                }
            }
        }

        CurrentFloor = i;

        next2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int NewFloor;
        System.out.println("Current Level:" + CurrentFloor);

        infinite loop;
        for (;;) {

            System.out.println("Please Choose a Floor:");
            NewFloor = next2.nextInt();
            if ((NewFloor > 7) || (NewFloor < 0) || (NewFloor == 7)) {
                System.out.println("\nWrong Floor Selected");
            }

            else if ((NewFloor <= 7) && (NewFloor > 0) && (NewFloor != 7)) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= NewFloor; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Floor Level: " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                {
                    System.out.println("Your at Your Destination - Floor:" + NewFloor);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Doors Closing");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Floor Level: " + NewFloor);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    // The code only reprints from 0 i want it to print from the
                    // NewFloor
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question ?

Comment: how do i get the lift to scan from the floor that the user gets out at and not again from 0?

Comment: You should somehow store the last floor that was reached by the lift and start the `for` loop at this number.

Comment: This will also imply that your loop need to iterate backwards if the new floor is smaller than the current floor.

Answer (score 0):

You should init your i : `private static int i = 0;`

I think what you miss is that you never change the value of your `CurrentFloor`

You should change your code to :

```
    infinite loop;
    for (;;) {

        System.out.println("Please Choose a Floor:");
        NewFloor = next2.nextInt();
        if ((NewFloor >= 7) || (NewFloor < 0)) {
            System.out.println("\nWrong Floor Selected");
        }
        else if (CurrentFloor == NewFloor)
        {
           System.out.println("You are already at this floor");
           continue;
        }
        else if ((NewFloor < 7) && (NewFloor > 0)) 
        {
            if( CurrentFloor < NewFloor )
            {
                for (int i = CurrentFloor; i <= NewFloor; i++) {
                System.out.println("Floor Level: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                for (int i = CurrentFloor; i >= NewFloor; i--) {
                System.out.println("Floor Level: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            {
                System.out.println("Your at Your Destination - Floor:" + NewFloor);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("Doors Closing");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Floor Level: " + NewFloor);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                // The code only reprints from 0 i want it to print from the
                // NewFloor
                CurrentFloor = NewFloor; // change the value of your currentFloor
            }
        }
    }
```

I let you see what else you want to add.

Comment: thank you for this feedback it was really helpful and allowed for the code to do what i wanted the rest i should be able to do myself thanks a lot Clad Clad and the rest for all your advice

Comment: No prob ;) don't forget to validate the answer if it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is:

```
((NewFloor > 6) || (NewFloor < 0))
```

will do the job, instead of:

```
((NewFloor > 7) || (NewFloor < 0) || (NewFloor == 7))
```

Secondly you can start like this:

```
 for (int i = CurrentFloor; i <= NewFloor; i=(CurrentFloor>NewFloor)? i+1:i-1) {
                if (CurrentFloor==NewFloor)   { System.out.println("You are already on:); }
                System.out.println("Floor Level: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
//and add this statement which will keep the track of the last user get out floor
CurrentFloor=NewFloor;
```